# What are Folium style_function parameters

Tags: python, leaflet, style, folium

I'm trying to do a uniform style for each polygon, but I want to know further about what I can do with Python library Folium Style_function. What can I put in the style variable? Where are the resources that I can look up to?

```
style = {'fillColor': '#f5f5f5', 'lineColor': '#ffffbf'}    
polygon = folium.GeoJson(gjson, style_function = lambda x: style).add_to(m)
```

I know that the style variable should be a dictionary, and I looked at the [documentation](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html?highlight=style_function). It seems like every resource that I have encountered has been trivial from other topics.

Comment: if you're confused by the 'lineColor' in the question, the parameter is 'color' for the line color (see answers below for more details on all params)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Geojson layer's `style_function` mimics [the `style` function from Leaflet.js](https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/). [Here](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#path-option) are all the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path-option) is an updated link to the Leaflet style parameters.